# Hibernate 5, Criteria Query for where clause with 2 restrictions

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, criteria, hibernate-criteria, predicatebuilder

For an Employee Table

```
public class Employee {
    
    private Long id;
    
    private int deptId;
    
    private String name;
    
    private LocalDateTime joiningDate;
    
    private LocalDateTime seperatedDate;

}
```

I want build a criteria with both of the below condition

```
criteriaQuery.where((EmployeeRoot.get("deptId").in(request.getDeptIdList())));
criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(EmployeeRoot.get("joiningDate"), startDate));
```

**But it only takes the latest Predicate. How can i combine both like [Where {condition1} + AND {condition2}] ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```java
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Employee> criteria = builder.createQuery(Employee.class);
Root<Employee> root = criteria.from(Employee.class);
criteria
  .select(...)
  .where(
      builder.and(
         root.get("deptId").in(request.getDeptIdList()),
         builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("joiningDate"), startDate))
      )
  );
entityManager.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```